# Oracle Apex Update rows with column as Yes

Tags: oracle-apex

I need some advice on the below scenario:

I have a grid of employee details.

The grid as default IG save that saves data locally.

It has another process button in which a functionality needs to be added, such that employees with promote_to_upgrade column value set as Yes only need to be moved to the upgraded_employee tables.

In the processing can i add condiiton like:

IF :PROMOTE_TO_UPGRADE = 'Yes' --Here PROMOTE_TO_UPGRADE is column in EMPLOYEES table and is select list with Yes or No values in grid.

Then --insert into upgraded_employees............

Will this condition work?

Comment: Are you using the default save processing or custom ?

Comment: I am using both. Default save is for local saving of data. The custom save button is to push the data to another table. There we need to remodify and add condition so that only column with promote_to_upgrade as Yes shall get inserted.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I did the following test:

- Create an editable IG on the EMP table, IG name "IG on emp"
- added an attional process after the native process with following attributes:
- Editable Region: "IG on emp"
- Source:

```
begin
    if :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'D' then
        apex_debug.info(
            p_message => q'#kl debug - DELETE: ENAME: %0#',
            p0        => :ENAME);
         
    elsif :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'U' then
        apex_debug.info(
            p_message => q'#kl debug - UPDATE: ENAME: %0#',
            p0        => :ENAME);
    elsif :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'C' then
        apex_debug.info(
            p_message => q'#kl debug - CREATE: ENAME: %0#',
            p0        => :ENAME);
    end if;
end;
```

Run the page in debug mode, make some changes, save and investigate the debug. It shows that the native DML process is executed and that this process is executed after this. So this will work.

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow... Where do i add the column condition here where if set to Yes the insert should run?

Comment: In any of the "if" branches. There are 3 cases in which this will fire for a changed row: Delete (D), Update (U), Create (C). Just add your code in the appropriate place or rewrite the block. I just gave an example of code that does something on submit of an IG, up to you to adjust it to your needs